# CartoDB Runtime Layers with Angular

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js, angularjs

Has anyone ever tried adding a [CartoDB runtime layer](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#creating-visualizations-at-runtime) to a leaflet using an Angular Directive or [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) (Leaflet Javascript Library)?

I tried this, which does not throw errors but my layer doesn't show.  Is this a digest cycle issue?

```
angular.module('cartoDbDirectives', []).directive('cdbRuntime', function(){

 return {
  restrict: "A",
  scope: false,
  replace: false,

  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, controller){

    var map = L.map("mapCanvas", {
      zoom: 9,
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 19,
      center: [38.98, -75.511667], 
      zoomControl: false,
    });

    cartodb.createLayer(map, {
      user_name: 'czajk',
      type: 'cartodb',
      sublayers: [{
        sql: 'select crossing, the_geom_webmercator from crossings',
        cartocss:'#crossings{marker-fill:#ff0000;}',
        interactivity: 'crossing'
      }]
    })
    .addTo(map);
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that one way to do this is using the [CartoDB Core API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#core-api-functionallity).  Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eczajk1/ok0nseom/

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to diagnose your problem without trying to reproduce it. Do you mind assembling a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can better assist you?

Using a hardcoded reference to an element is frowned upon in Angular. Try to use the element reference the directive receives as the second parameter instead:

```
var map = L.map(elm, {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @PauloScardine.  I haven't done this much, obviously.